# Activity has leaked window that was originally added (no Dialog attached)

Tags: android, android-activity

I get the following error message:

```
"Activity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@417521e0 that was originally added here..."
```

I checked the other stackoverflow threads but they all deal with Activities that have attached Dialogs. I don't have, I only use my `PreloadActivity` to display a static (by the way black) screen while starting another `Activity` (which has a fade-in from black, so this is OK). My code is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("myapp", "PreloadActivity.onCreate");
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Set full screen mode and disable the keyguard (lockscreen)
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN  
                         | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD 
                         | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                         | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.preload);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    Log.d("myapp", "PreloadActivity.onStart");
    super.onStart();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.d("myapp", "PreloadActivity.onResume");
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyMainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(0, 0); // no animation
    finish(); 
}
```

What is 'leaked' here? Does it matter?

**UPDATE**: the relevant logcat part (including the stack trace). The device is HTC One V.

```
08-11 19:31:37.438: D/myapp(11724): PreloadActivity.onCreate
08-11 19:31:37.488: D/myapp(11724): PreloadActivity.onStart
08-11 19:31:37.488: D/myapp(11724): PreloadActivity.onResume
08-11 19:31:37.508: D/myapp(11724): PreloadActivity.onPause
08-11 19:31:37.708: D/myapp(11724): MyMainActivity.onCreate started 
08-11 19:31:39.200: D/myapp(11724): MyMainActivity.onCreate finished, time: 1530 ms
08-11 19:31:39.200: D/myapp(11724): MyMainActivity.onStart started
08-11 19:31:39.320: D/myapp(11724): MyMainActivity.onStart finished
08-11 19:31:39.320: D/myapp(11724): MyMainActivity.onResume started
08-11 19:31:39.350: D/myapp(11724): MyMainActivity.onResume finished
08-11 19:31:39.430: D/dalvikvm(11724): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 573K, 5% free 15070K/15779K, paused 20ms
08-11 19:31:42.153: D/myapp(11724): MyMainActivity.onPause started 
08-11 19:31:42.203: I/myapp(11724): GLSurfaceView has been paused
08-11 19:31:42.243: D/myapp(11724): MyMainActivity.onPause finished
08-11 19:31:42.733: D/myapp(11724): PreloadActivity.onStop
08-11 19:31:42.753: D/myapp(11724): PreloadActivity.onDestroy
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724): Activity mypackage.PreloadActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@417521e0 that was originally added here
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity mypackage.PreloadActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@417521e0 that was originally added here
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:380)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:372)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:320)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl$CompatModeWrapper.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:152)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:557)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:301)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.showNavigationBarTips(PhoneWindow.java:3936)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.access$1600(PhoneWindow.java:123)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$2.run(PhoneWindow.java:3099)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:608)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:156)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4977)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-11 19:31:43.194: E/WindowManager(11724):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-11 19:31:43.274: D/myapp(11724): SaveTheAdventurersActivity.onStop() started
08-11 19:31:43.304: D/myapp(11724): SaveTheAdventurersActivity.onStop() finished
```

Comment: Can you post the entire stack trace?

Comment: I've just posted all relevant logcat, including the stacktrace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you finish a particular instance of activity and try to start a new activity, service or to stop it using that instance then this kind of error occurrs e.g...

```
OldActivity instance;

oncreate()
{
   instance=this;
}

method() {
instance.finish();
instance.startActivity(new Intent(ACTION_MAIN).setClass(instance, NewActivity.class));
}
```